# coding to find the limit of x^2 c++

Tags: c++, limit

cannot figure out the issue with my program. I am trying to calculate the limit within the margin for some reason i dont think the while loop is initializing. I am very novice. Please help. i dont know what i am doing wrong.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cmath>

double f(double);

using namespace std;

void main()
{
    //main program variable declarations
    double x_0, h, prev, newapprox, diffapprox; double const tol = 0.000001;

    cout << setiosflags(ios::showpoint | ios::fixed) << setprecision(7);

    cout << "\n Enter the value at which the limit will be calculated: ";
    cin >> x_0;

    h = 1;
    prev = f(x_0 + h);

    cout << "\n x0+h" << setw(25) << "f(x0+h)" << endl;
    cout << x_0 + h << setw(25) << prev << endl;

    newapprox = f(x_0 + h/2);
    cout << x_0 + h/2 << setw(25) << newapprox << endl;

    diffapprox = fabs(prev - newapprox);

    while (diffapprox > .00001);
    {
        prev = newapprox;

        cout << "\n x0+h" << setw(25) << "f(x0+h)" << endl;
        cout << x_0 + h << setw(25) << prev << endl;

        newapprox = f(x_0 + h);
        cout << x_0 + h << setw(25) << newapprox << endl;

        diffapprox = fabs(prev - newapprox);

        h /= 2;
    }

        if (fabs(diffapprox) <= 0.00001)
        {
            cout << "\n\n The limit exists and has the value" << diffapprox;
        }
        else
        {
            cout << "\n\n The limit does not exist at " << x_0;
        }


        system("pause");

    }


double f(double x_0)
{
    return pow(x_0, 2.0);
}
```

Comment: Debugging is an important part of programming. You have an excellent learning opportunity! Use a debugger and/or read [how to debug small programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). Also, [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: What's the actual problem?

Answer (score 1):

The condition for your `while` loop is `diffapprox > .00001`. `diffapprox` is computed from `fabs(prev - newapprox)`. `prev` is computed from `f(x_0 + h)` and `newapprox` is computed from `f(x_0 + h/2)` where `h = 1.0`, `f(x)` is x^2, and x_0 is gotten from user input.

From this, we can say that `prev` is `(x_0 + 1.0)^2 = x_0^2 + 2(x_0) + 1` while `newapprox` is `(x_0 + 1.0/2)^2 = (x_0 + 0.5)^2 = x_0^2 + x_0 + 0.25`. This gives the difference of `(x_0^2 + 2(x_0) + 1) - (x_0^2 + x_0 + 0.25) = x_0 + 0.75`.

Therefore, the initial condition for the `while` loop to begin, `fabs(prev - newapprox) > .00001`, fails when `fabs(x_0 + 0.75) <= .00001`, or when `x_0` is within +/- .00001 of 0.75.